# Compare list of array to object javascript

Tags: javascript

I try to check from list of array element that  same to as id object property then return (a) each array element as (tag) name object property to new element in dom

```
a= [28,32],
   [28,32,56]

b = {id:28, name:action},
    {id:32, name:horror},
    {id:56, name:comedy},
```

Result should be

```
Action horror


----------


Action horror comedy
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, first, correct the `a` - it can't be declared this way: are both `a` and `b` arrays? Then show what you have done so far and where you struggle at :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```js
const a = [
    [28,32],
    [28,32,56]
];

const b = [
    {id:28, name:'action'},
    {id:32, name:'horror'},
    {id:56, name:'comedy'},
];

const data = a.map(item => item.map(id => b.filter(bItem => bItem.id === id).map(item => item.name)).join(' '));
console.log(data);
```

Comment: thank..this save me headache from running api in api